# delphi7 create component from table fields

Tags: delphi

I want to create components (Panels) on run-time in Delphi 7 from a table, but only create if the field value is > 0.
Example:
widht |p1|p2|p3|p4|p5|p6|p7|..|px|
1500 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |..|0 | // create 3 panels
2700 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 6 | 6 | 0 | 0 |..|0 | // create 5 panels
.......

```
 private
{ Private declarations }
pn : array of TPanel;
..................................

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var i: integer;
oldpn: TComponent;
begin
table1.SetKey;
table1.FindNearest([form2.Edit2.Text]);
i:= table1.FieldCount;
SetLength(pn, i);
for i:= 1 to i-1 do
 begin
  oldpn:= Findcomponent('pn'+inttostr(i));
  oldpn.Free;
  pn[i]:= TPanel.Create(form1);
  pn[i].Parent := form1;
  pn[i].Caption := 'Panel' + inttostr(i);
  pn[i].Name := 'pn'+inttostr(i);
  pn[i].Height := table1.Fields[i].Value ;
  pn[i].Width := 500;
  pn[i].Color:=clGreen;
  pn[1].Top := form1.ClientHeight - pn[1].Height;
  if (i > 1) then pn[i].Top := pn[i-1].Top - pn[i].Height;
  pn[i].OnClick := pnClick;
 end;
end;
```

This code create me the panels but for ALL fields. I want to be able to declare the 'pn' array only from fields with value > 0...
I ve tried:
 if table1.Fields[i].Value > 0 then
begin
i:= table1.FieldCount....
but it does't work. Any idea? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a second "counter" which keeps track of the number of elements that you're actually setting in the array.  I'd set the array to the *maximum* possible length (your Table1.FieldCount as your have now).  Then, once you've looped through all your fields, set the length of the array to that "counter" value.

Something like:

```
procedure TForm1.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var i: integer;
oldpn: TComponent;
count: Integer; // this keeps count of the number of panels you'll be creating
begin
  tbl1.SetKey;
  tbl1.FindNearest([form2.Edit2.Text]);
  i := tbl1.FieldCount;
  SetLength(pn, i);
  count := 0; // initialise count to 0
  for i := 1 to i - 1 do
    if tbl1.fields[1].value > 0 then
    begin
      oldpn := Findcomponent('pn' + inttostr(count));
      oldpn.Free;
      pn[count] := TPanel.Create(form1);
      pn[count].Parent := form1;
      pn[count].Caption := 'Panel' + inttostr(count);
      pn[count].Name := 'pn' + inttostr(count);
      pn[count].Height := tbl1.fields[count].value;
      pn[count].Width := 500;
      pn[count].Color := clGreen;
      pn[0].Top := form1.ClientHeight - pn[0].Height;
      if (count > 0) then
        pn[count].Top := pn[count - 1].Top - pn[count].Height;
      pn[count].OnClick := pnClick;
      inc(count);
    end;

  SetLength(pn, count); // re-adjust length of array
end;
```

There may be better ways to implement it but this seems simple enough.

Also, with your line:

```
pn[1].Top := form1.ClientHeight - pn[1].Height;
```

Are you trying to set it to the bottom of the form?  You may be better to change that line to (and the next line too) a single if statement to prevent it being executed every time your loop goes round:

```
if (count = 0) then
  pn[0].Top := form1.ClientHeight - pn[0].Height;
else
  pn[count].Top := pn[count - 1].Top - pn[count].Height;
```

Comment: Thank you Jason. It's working good. ..and yes I want to arrange the panels from the bottom of the form to top. I change the if / else too but it's put the panel 1 on top of the others and i want it on the bottom(from bottom to top: pn1 pn2,pn3..pnx)... but with a few changes i hope to make it work. Thank you once again.

Comment: yes, count starts at 0... I will edit the last bit of my answer to reflect what it should read

Comment: yesss. that solve the problem. ...and a little edit (if someone else want to use this...) :if tbl[1].fields[1].value > 0 then ...must be : if tbl1.fields[i].value > 0 then... . If is 1 not i will create panels for all the fields else will create only for fields[i].val > 0. All the rest run like butter :). Thanks a lot!!!